# ngrx/store state not updating in reducer function called

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am starting to add ngrx(8.4.0) to an existing Angular(8.2) application but one of my actions (see action below) when triggered does not mutate state.

auth.actions.ts (partial)

```js
export const loginSuccess = createAction(
  '[SIGN IN] Login Success',
  props<{ user: any; isNewUser: boolean }>()
```

The `loginSuccess` action is handled by the reducer function below.

auth.reducer.ts (partial)

```js
export interface AuthState {
  user: any;
  isNewUser: boolean;
}

export const initialState: AuthState = {
  user: null,
  isNewUser: null
};

const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(loginSuccess, (state, { user, isNewUser }) => ({
    ...state,
    user: user,
    isNewUser: isNewUser
  }))
);

export function reducer(state: AuthState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return authReducer(state, action);
}
```

The `loginSuccess` action is dispatched from an effect called `loginWithPopUp`.

```js
  loginWithPopUp$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(authActions.loginWithPopUp),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(action =>
        from(this.authService.signUpWithPopUp()).pipe(
          map((result: firebase.auth.UserCredential) =>
            authActions.loginSuccess({
              user: result.user,
              isNewUser: result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
            })
          ),
          tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/notes'])),
          catchError(() => of(authActions.loginFail()))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Even though my action is triggered and I see the properties `user` and `isNewUser` in my action, state is not updated.

[image: unchanged state]

`user` and `isNewUser` populated in the action.

[image: action]

Error that appears on the console.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code on stackblitz or github ?

Comment: @TonyNgo this is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/github/dpetla/Menote/tree/feature-ngrx) for you to see the code but some modification is necessary to login since it's using Google sign in and it's not configured to accept that domain. I can try changing that later. (if you get an issue installing `core-js` try installing `core-js@2` instead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems fine, can you verify that:

- the reducer is called, you can put a console.log or a debug statement in there
- make sure the user and isNewUser is populated on the action, you can do this by clicking on the action toggle in the devtools

Comment: The action has both properties populated and I was not able to console.log them because a `TypeError: Cannot freeze` error is thrown. (updated the post with these details)

Comment: What about adding `console.log(action)` inside the exported reducer function?

Comment: I just tried it again to confirm and it did not print anything to the console besides the an error, but this time the error was `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
    at Object.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.Firestore.configureClient`, I'll try to understand this error better later today.

Comment: That's weird, it seems like NgRx isn't the problem here. Do you also get the error if you remove the log statement? If you can reproduce it inside a stackblitz/github repo I'm happy to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same problem, and finally I figured out (even if not completely) the problem of this issue.
It seems that passing the full `result.user` generates the error, try to pass the UID instead, or something similar.

Comment: Oddly enough, this solved it for me. Thanks for sharing that info, it was banging my head against the wall trying to figure this one out haha